# Why is the bootstrap col not taking 12 columns automatically?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make three cards behaving in a way in Bootstrap.

All three cards stack horizontally in laptop view and above (col-lg-4). This works fine.

First two cards stack up horizontally in iPad view while the last card stacks vertically below them (col-md-6 for first two and col-md-12 for last card). This works fine as well.

Since I didn't declare the behavior for mobile, I expect all three cards to automatically stack up vertically in small screen (mobile and below), but this isn't the case. The first two just take 6 cols each for mobile and even smaller screens.

I have tried adding the default `col` class to the first two but they don't work as well.

```
    <div class="col col-lg-4 col-md-6">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h3>Chihuahua</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h2>Free</h2>
          <p>5 Matches Per Day</p>
          <p>10 Messages Per Day</p>
          <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
          <button type="button">Sign Up</button>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col col-lg-4 col-md-6">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h3>Labrador</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h2>$49 / mo</h2>
          <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
          <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
          <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
          <button type="button">Sign Up</button>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h3>Mastiff</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h2>$99 / mo</h2>
          <p>Pirority Listing</p>
          <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
          <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
          <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
          <button type="button">Sign Up</button>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

I expect all cards to stack up vertically when I go to mobile view, the first two in a horizontal line when I'm in iPad view but the third in vertical below them. But first two remains in horizontal line while 3rd is below in mobile and even smaller screens.

Comment: you need col-12 (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#all-breakpoints)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this is what you want. This solution is for  Bootstrap 3. If you are working on Bootstrap 4, then you will have to do some grid adjustments.

```
 <div class="container-fluid">

     <div class="row">

         <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
             <div class="card">
                 <div class="card-header">
                     <h3>Chihuahua</h3>
                 </div>
                 <div class="card-body">
                     <h2>Free</h2>
                     <p>5 Matches Per Day</p>
                     <p>10 Messages Per Day</p>
                     <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
                     <button type="button">Sign Up</button>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>

         <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
             <div class="card">
                 <div class="card-header">
                    <h3>Labrador</h3>
                 </div>
                 <div class="card-body">
                     <h2>$49 / mo</h2>
                     <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
                     <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
                     <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
                     <button type="button">Sign Up</button>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>

         <div class="col-md-4 visible-xs visible-md visible-lg">
             <div class="card">
                 <div class="card-header">
                     <h3>Mastiff</h3>
                 </div>
                 <div class="card-body">
                     <h2>$99 / mo</h2>
                     <p>Pirority Listing</p>
                     <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
                     <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
                     <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
                     <button type="button">Sign Up</button>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>

         <div class="row visible-sm">
             <div class="col-sm-12">
                 <div class="card">
                     <div class="card-header">
                         <h3>Mastiff</h3>
                     </div>
                     <div class="card-body">
                         <h2>$99 / mo</h2>
                         <p>Pirority Listing</p>
                         <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
                         <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
                         <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
                         <button type="button">Sign Up</button>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div> 
         </div>

     </div>

 </div>
```